# How can I use the s3a file system on an EMR using Flink?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am attempting to leverage the s3a file system in a Flink application using the Table API. I am on EMR 6.1 (that comes prepackaged with Flink 1.11.0).

I am creating a table over an s3 location as part of my application. When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException
```

Indicating that there are no supported file systems for neither an s3:// or s3a:// URI.

Per [Flink's documentation on using s3](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins), if I am on EMR I do not need to configure any file systems as a plugin.

I have double checked that I am not including the fs-s3-hadoop dependency in my application.

Oddly enough, when I do follow the above directions for installing the file system as a plugin I can get this to work for s3:// URIs but not s3a:// ones.

It seems that the flink run command is not honoring the hadoop classpath pre-configured by the EMR.

I additionally wish to use a s3 custom credentials provider to supplement my application, but this also does not appear to work when used via a plugin system nor does it get picked up from the Hadoop classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use s3:// URLs

1. the s3a connector is the Apache open source one, in hadoop-aws
2. the flink documentations is open source, and refers to s3a
3. the s3 connector is from EMR.
4. And EMR does not contain/support the s3a connector
5. which leads to the stack trace you see

Comment: Oh, interesting, my use case requires me to actually use s3a so it appears I will have to try providing it myself. I think this is helpful, thank you!

Comment: serious q: why the s3a connector...what does it do which the EMR one doesn't -and which you actually need?

Comment: I have a use case requiring a proprietary library that only works with the s3a file system. Otherwise I'd be using EMRFS proper.

Comment: oh well, unlucky. I hope they aren't using any of the internal use only APIs you get if you cast the FileSystem to S3AFileSystem and then invoke...they are very brittle and if something breaks we only feel guilt if it's another OSS project (HBase etc)